# Firebase "No content provider" error for imageview

Tags: android, firebase, uri

I am working on an app where I have uploaded images to Firebase, then I use a query to look for an image based on its name, I display it in an imageview, then I try to upload this image to a different table in the same firebase database.
My problem is that when I try to upload the image to the other table, I get a `No content provider` error, and in front of it is a fully working link to my image (I click on it and my image is displayed in the browser).

Here is the code that I have tried :

```
private void addToMenu(){    
    final Query query = mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(EditTextName.getText().toString());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot NamedImage : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        SliderUtils sliderUtils = NamedImage.getValue(SliderUtils.class);
                        Uri uriFile = Uri.parse(sliderUtils.getImageUrl());
                        StorageReference Ref= menuStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"."+getPath(uriFile));
                        mStorageTask = Ref.putFile(uriFile)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                            progressBar.setProgress(0);
                                        }
                                    }, 500);



Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully.", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils(EditTextName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                            taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                        String uploadId = menuDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                                    menuDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(sliderUtils);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image upload failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            })

                            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                                        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                                }
                            });

                }
            }
```

}

the getPath() function is the following:

```
    private String getPath(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mimeTypeMap= MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mimeTypeMap.getExtensionFromMimeType(cr.getType(uri));
    }
```

The error I get is :

```
/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: No content provider: https://firebase...
```

Do you have any idea where the problem is please?

Answer (score 0):

for anyone in the same situation and looking for a solution:
**A big mistake that I had is that I was trying to turn an URL into a URI which is simply impossible**
So I decided to change the way that I was uploading my image altogether. Here is the code:

```
 private void addToMenu(){
        final Query query = 
mDatabaseRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(EditTextName.getText().toString());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot NamedImage : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        SliderUtils sliderUtils = NamedImage.getValue(SliderUtils.class);
                        StorageReference Ref= menuStorageRef.child("filename" + new Date().getTime());

                        image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                        image.buildDrawingCache();
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                        UploadTask uploadTask = Ref.putBytes(data);
                        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image upload failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image uploaded successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils(EditTextName.getText().toString().trim(),
                                    taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
                                String uploadId = menuDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            menuDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(sliderUtils);
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```